# Bounded sequence in Sobolev space H^1[0,1] has convergent subsequence in C[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis

I am wondering anyone could give me some ideas? I am thinking it should invlove the Sobolev embeding theorem.

Comment: You may try to show that the sequence is equicontinuous (and equibounded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\in C^1[0,1]$. Then for any $x,y\in[0,1]$ with $x<y$ we have
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\int_x^y|f'(t)|dt\leq\left(\int_x^y|f'(t)|^2dt\right)^{\frac12}\left(\int_x^ydt\right)^{\frac12}\leq|f|_{H^1}\sqrt{|x-y|} ,
$$
by Cauchy-Schwarz. By density, the sequence is equicontinuous.

To show that the sequence is equibounded, start with
$$
|f(x)|\leq|f(y)|+|f(x)-f(y)|,
$$
and square it, to get
$$
|f(x)|^2\leq2|f(y)|^2+2|f(x)-f(y)|^2.
$$
Now an integration over $[0,1]$ yields
$$
|f(x)|^2
\leq2\int_0^1|f(y)|^2dy+2\int_0^1|f(x)-f(y)|^2dy
\leq2\|f\|_{L^2}^2+2|f|_{H^1}^2
$$
implying
$$
\|f\|_{L^\infty}
\leq\sqrt2\|f\|_{H^1}.
$$
I leave the density argument as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering why we can pick $f$ in $C^1$, I thought the restriction is $C^0$.

Comment: @000000000: That's the density argument left as an exercise. Think about how you prove that the elements of $H^1$ are continuous in the first place.

Comment: @timur when you integrate $|f(x)|^2\leq2|f(y)|^2+2|f(x)-f(y)|^2.$ over$ [0,1]$, I think thereexist a constant messing in the inequality that follows or I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The result that you look for exist in  https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387709130 theorem 8.8 page 213

Answer (score 0):

Say $\|f_n\|_{H^1}\le C$. By Morrey's inequality, $\|f_n\|_{C^{1/2}} \le C $. Thus $\|f_n\|_{L^\infty}\le C$ i.e. $f_n$ are uniformly bounded and $\sup_n|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\le C|x-y|^{1/2}$ i.e. $f_n$ is equicontinuous. The result follows by Arzela-Ascoli.